# How to access Microsoft Asp.Net Identity in Quartz Scheduler or console scheduler in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership, quartz.net

How to access Microsoft Asp.Net Identity in Quartz Scheduler or console scheduler in C# ?
Actually I just need when user is not confirmed email then scheduler can send re-confirm email by Microsoft Asp.Net Identity

My Code in below-

**JobScheduler.cs**

```
using Quartz;
using Quartz.Impl;

namespace Demo.Web.ScheduledTask
{
    public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ReConfirmEmailScheduler>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
            .RepeatForever())
            .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
}
```

**ReConfirmEmailScheduler.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Demo.Identity;
using Quartz;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace Demo.Web.ScheduledTask
{
    public class ReConfirmEmailScheduler : IJob
    {

        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }



        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {

            var _userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            if (Keys.IsStartScheduler)
            {
                ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var users = db.Users.Where(x => x.EmailConfirmed==false).ToList();
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    string code = _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id).Result;
                    var callbackUrl = SiteKeys.Domain + "/Account/ConfirmEmail?userId=" + user.Id + "&code=" + code;
                    _userManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Demo : Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                }
                db.Dispose();
            }

        }
```

Is there any other way for that for send email which user is not confirm own email (using Microsoft Asp.Net Identity).

The issue that var user=HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();

user is getting NULL.

Comment: @OP Did you found the solution?

Comment: I ended up having to trigger an internal custom web-api call from within itself to get access to the context. It needs the bootstrap of HttpContext to exist and operate. And quartz runs on it's own thread. So my job now makes a webrequest internally passing the job name, which I exposed an interface on containing a public method with param of HttpContext, and the web api call uses the IScheduler instance to locate the job, cast to my interface, and execute the method as needed in a "combined" context. 
I know of no other way.